# Instagram embed box not loading embed code... anyone know a workaround?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, video-embedding, instagram-reels

I am trying to copy the embed code from a single Instagram reel by clicking  the ... menu and clicking Embed. However, the code never loads and I get this screen. Anyone know a workaround to embed an Instagram reel on a website? The specific reel is: https://www.instagram.com/reel/Cd56By5FxBF/

See screenshot for what loads when I try to use to embed function on instagram. I have tried on multiple browsers.

[image: where the embed should be... but it never loads]

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

The integration code is made up of two elements. A long `<blockquote>` followed by a short `<script>`.

The `<script>` element should look something like this:

```html
<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Just add `https:` to the value of the `src` attribute, thus:

```html
<script async src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

And everything should be working fine.